# How can i pick material theme in preview?

Tags: android

I want to use Material.Light.Panel theme when i'm using AndroidStudio preview,but in Select Theme dialog, I cannot find it.

[image]

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dslx.electronicclassboard"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters  "armeabi","armeabi-v7a"
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

}
```

How can I find this theme?

Answer (score 1):

Add Dependency for Material Theme in your app gradle.
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'`
Then change theme in your styles.xml to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">`.
After that change the preview theme you can find the option for material themes as shown in the image.[image: Sample theme selector image]

Comment: thanks first,i did what you said,but it don't work.My AndroidStudio version is 3.3

Comment: My Android Studio version is also 3.3, But sometimes Studio behaves like this. If you have `Project Themes` option then select your current `AppTheme` from it, it will select Material Theme because you've already defined your `AppTheme` as `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` in your styles.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The theme is not set in your build.gradle, but in a styles.xml file located under res->layout->values

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

From here you can set the theme for your app in your manifest file

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```